# How to: GET Data from 2 APIs, compare, POST bool

Tags: node.js, api, express, request, async-await

I'm working on a project that requires me to:

1. GET IDs from API1, push the IDs into an array, then map over those IDs, using them for a second GET request, where IDs are used as params for API2 GET request, populates an array with IDs or N for "Not existing" -- this array is then called in:
2. A POST request. This post maps over the returned array from the GET request. IF the item is not "N", it POSTS to API1 with checked: true. IF the item is "N", it emails us telling us API2 is missing this project.

I want this system to automatically do a GET and POST every 2 hours, so I'm using setInterval (not sure this is the best idea). EDIT: Cron job would be a better solution.

I'm working with NodeJS, Express, Request-Promise, Async / Await.

Here is some of my pseudo code so far:

```
// Dependencies
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({ apiKey, domain });

// Static
const app = express();


app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  // Replace setInterval with Cron job in deployment

  // Get All Ids
  const orders = await getGCloud();

  // Check if IDs exist in other API
  const validations = await getProjectManagementSystem(orders);

  // If they exist, POST update to check, else, mailer
  validations.map(id => {
    if (id !== 'n') {
      postGCloud(id);
    } else {
      mailer(id);
    }
  });   
}

// Method gets all IDs
const getGCloud = async () => {
  try {
    let orders = [];
    const response = await axios.get('gCloudURL');
    for (let key in response) {
      orders.push(response.key);
    }
    return orders;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
  }
}

// Method does a GET requst for each ID
const getProjectManagementSystem = async orders => {
  try {
    let idArr = [];
    orders.map(id => {
      let response = await axios.get(`projectManagementSystemURL/${id}`);
      response === '404' ? idArr.push('n') : idArr.push(response)
    })
    return idArr;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
  }
}

const postGCloud = id => {
  axios.post('/gcloudURL', {
    id,
    checked: true
  })
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

const mailer = id => {
  const data = {
    from: 'TESTER <test@test.com>',
    to: 'customerSuppoer@test.com',
    subject: `Missing Order: ${id}`,
    text: `Our Project Management System is missing ${id}. Please contact client.`    
  }

  mailgun.messages().send(data, (err, body) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error: ', err)
    } else {
      console.log('Body: ', body);
    }
  });
}

app.listen(6000, () => console.log('LISTENING ON 6000'));
```

The TL;DR: Need to do a GET request to API 1, then another GET request to API 2 following it (using IDs from API 1 as params), then send data from second GET to a POST request that then either updates API 1's data or emails Customer support. This is an automatic system that runs every two hours.

Main Questions:
1. Is it okay to have a setInterval in a get req?
2. Can I have a GET request automatically call a POST request?
3. If so, how can I pass GET request data onto a POST request?

Comment: there are probably a ton of errors in this -- but it's my untested thought process. not entirely sure i can automate this system -- is this even possible?

Comment: Have you tried it using promises I hope promises will help you in this context

Comment: i could omit the async await and instead make a promise for the two GET requests -- but you can make a promise from GET to a POST?

Comment: Yes You can Use Express Middleware for that purpose.

Comment: do you have a reference example of Express Middleware using GET to POST and passing on data? much appreciated

Comment: in this case, would i only wrap the first get request in the setinterval, since everything else will follow?

Comment: i just updated the code . . .

Comment: i need to do more research. i probably am not passing in the data into next properly (maybe yield?) i think i can go from get to post... if i use next?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I was away, Sorry I didn't get what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Hey there. My main questions for this are:
1. Is it okay to have a setInterval in a get req?
2. Can I have a GET request automatically call a POST request?
3. If so, how can I pass GET request data onto a POST request?

Comment: Looking into using axios for the 2 GETs to POST idea

Comment: Why don’t you do a xhr request from get call to your post method with all the data you want to use in your post method?

Comment: Can I call an Axios POST in a GET route after I do my two Axios GET requests? Is that strange to call a POST inside a GET route? I'm refactoring right now . . . I may be able to make this work

Comment: Yes, you can use that

Comment: i updated the code -- would this potentially work? thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, as per you requirements this will work

Comment: It will be nice if i put this precise information in answer and you do accept?

Comment: i need to unit test it first but as soon as i get it working i'll post here and let you know if it's the proper solution. i think this could help other developers out as well :)

Comment: Great, yes this will help

Comment: this works! feel free to post answer :)

Comment: Thanks and good to know that this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work for both of your calls one post and one get you have to do an Ajax call to get post processed information in another method.

I hope this works.